# How comparator and PriorityQueue in Java works?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

This is the code i used to reverse the normal working of priorityQueue in Java.
But i don't understand what is done by the lambda function i have put inside the parantheses. Can somedy explain that. 
 
PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<>(**(a,b) -> b - a**);

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> b - a);
        
        pq.add(2);
        pq.add(4);
        pq.add(1);
        pq.add(100);
        
        System.out.println(pq);
        System.out.println(pq.remove());
        System.out.println(pq.remove());
        System.out.println(pq.remove());
        System.out.println(pq.remove());
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison function is a function that must return any value less than `0` when the first parameter should be ordered before the second, any value greater than `0` when the second parameter should be ordered before the first and `0` if the two are equivalent for ordering.

It is used in within the `PriorityQueue` internally to determine relative ordering of elements by comparing its result with 0.